# Why does `open -a Terminal /tmp` open a terminal and then exit on macOS?

Tags: macos, shell

`$ open -a Terminal /tmp`

It will open a terminal but then instantly exit?

Passing other directories to `open` will work fine and open a terminal there, only one that causes an instant exit is `/tmp`.

Comment: Probably a security measure, opening Terminal is denied for all directories in / that are symbolically linked to /private/whatever.

Comment: Please consider moving this question to either [su] or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) as it doesn't seem to be a programming question.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen how would I move it? Or would I have to close it here and post it again there?

Comment: @Gereon but `open -a Terminal /tmp/dir` works.